# Inner/ Outer join in the Oracle Sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am trying to create a select query using joins

```
select distinct code from view req
inner join assoview assreq ON assreq.id_2 = req.id
where req.type_name = 'REQUEST' order by code
```

returns only the codes that has association like

```
ABC003
ABC005
```

But when I do a left join

```
select distinct code from view req
left join assoview assreq ON assreq.id_2 = req.id
where req.type_name = 'REQUEST' order by code
```

I get results as

```
ABC001
ABC002
ABC003
ABC004
ABC005
```

But I am looking how I can get the the code that has no association like

```
ABC001
ABC002
ABC004
```

Comment: modify your 2nd query to include in the where `and assreq.id is null`  Why?  LEFT Join includes all records from req and those that match from assreq.  by saying and assreq.id is null then you'll get all codes from req not in assreq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `left join` and `where . . . is null`:

```
select distinct code
from view req left join
     assoview assreq 
     on assreq.id_2 = req.id
where req.type_name = 'REQUEST' and
      assreq.id_2 is null
order by code;
```

You can also use `not in` or `not exists`, but this follows your current logic.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [`MINUS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) operator:

```
select code from view req
left join assoview assreq ON assreq.id_2 = req.id
where req.type_name = 'REQUEST'
MINUS 
select code from view req
inner join assoview assreq ON assreq.id_2 = req.id
where req.type_name = 'REQUEST'
order by code;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an "`IS NULL`" on a column of your `LEFT JOIN` table

```
   SELECT DISTINCT code 
     FROM view req
LEFT JOIN assoview assreq 
       ON assreq.id_2    = req.id
    WHERE req.type_name  = 'REQUEST' 
      AND assreq.id_2    IS NULL
 ORDER BY code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct code from view req
inner join assoview assreq ON assreq.id_2 <> req.id
where req.type_name = 'REQUEST' order by code
```